# How to test code inside an rxjs subscribe method call

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

So I have some code like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.openDialogWhenUploading();
}

openDialogWhenUploading() {
    this.store.select(getFileIsUploading).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.onDestory$),
        delay(1000)
    ).subscribe(uploading => {
        if(uploading === true) {
            this.dialog.open()
        }
    })
}
```

What I did to make easier to test was to return an observable from `openDialogWhenUploading` method and then subscribe on it in my test, something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.openDialogWhenUploading().subscribe();
}

openDialogWhenUploading() {
    return this.store.select(getFileIsUploading).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.onDestory$),
        delay(1000),
        tap(uploading => {
            if (uploading === true) {
                this.dialog.open()
            }
        })
    )
}
```

and in my test:

```
describe('openDialogWhenUploading', () => {
  it('should open dialog when uploading', () => {
    openDialogWhenUploading().subscribe(() => {
      expect(dialg.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
  })
})
```

any better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I think having a `filter` will be better? Since the name of your function already implies that the dialog can only be opened if and only if the operation is uploading:

```
openDialogWhenUploading() {
    this.store.select(getFileIsUploading)
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(this.onDestory$),
            delay(1000),
            filter(uploading=>uploading)
        );
}
```

And your test is perfectly fine and should remain.